# Solving weekday and weekend fare movies

Tags: knapsack

Thinking if it is a Knapsack  problem.

Here is the scenario:

Michael and his daughter (7 year old kid) enjoy going to cinema for movies.

```
Weekdays fare for kids is 5 dollars, adult 8.
Weekend fare $12.00, regardless kid or adult.
```

With $100 budget, how can Michael and his daughter enjoy more movies, considering most of those falls in weekdays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it costs \$13 for the two of them on a weekday and \$24 for the two of them on a weekend.  If you want to maximize the number of movies, skip the expensive ones and the \$100 budget yields $\lfloor 100/13 \rfloor = 7$ movies.

If you prefer writing it explicitly as an optimization (yes, knapsack) problem, let integer decision variables $x$ and $y$ be the numbers of weekday and weekend movies attended, respectively.  The problem is to maximize $x+y$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
13x+24y &\le 100 \\
x &\ge 0 \\
y &\ge 0 
\end{align}
The unique optimal solution is $(x,y)=(7,0)$, with objective value $7+0=7$.

Comment: thank you for the guidance! that's fantastic!